# cjs.Bitmap is not a constructor **Update 2**

Tags: createjs

I'm new to using Animate CC and I have created a project that has to be used with an in house CMS.

However I have implemented the code into the system webpage and all, but I keep being hit with this error `cjs.Bitmap is not a constructor` from the chrome console.

I am using the create.JS library but I am not sure how to solve the issue. I dont really dabble much in JavaScript as much since I am a designer is there anyone that can help?

**===Update===**

I have managed to remove the console errors but I am now having issues where the animation does not show at all when the page loads.

**===Update 2===**

So I figured out that the JS which has been generated by Animate CC does link the height and width directly to the canvas tag which also has the in-line height and width.

Comment: How did you remove the console errors?
I am having a similar issue:
 createjs.Rectangle is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the EaselJS library is not loaded. The Bitmap class is part of EaselJS, and the library exported from Flash/Animate requires EaselJS to be loaded before the library file.

Comment: I have included the full create js library as provided by Animate CC, however, I have now managed to removed the errors from the console but the animation now does not show.

Comment: Can you post a sample? There are lots of reasons why the content might not show. Are you testing locally, or using the "test movie" in Animate? What version of CreateJS is being used?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the JS which has been generated by Animate CC does link the height and width directly to the canvas tag which also has the in-line height and width.